# More beans in page

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2, xhtml

I'm new in JSF. 
I have a page xhtml where I use 3 bean.
Can i do this or the best way it's a big bean with same property ?

I ask this because the page is very slow.

Comment: Your performance problem is not caused by the amount of managed beans, but the amount of data it holds. Perhaps you're holding much more data than which is necessary to be presented. E.g. 10.000 records while you just need to display 10~100 at once. Run a profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way i think of is if your pages are in an aggregated way of showing the details in different panels, may be you load the panels using AJAX request to load the beans on demand. IMO a bigger bean with all the details is not a good seperation of concerns. Ideally the 3 beans which you are telling is logically grouped then it is good.